# Prevent multiple notification sounds android

Tags: android, notifications

I am working on a chat app in Android using c2dm (gcm). Every received message raises a notification if my app is not able to show it directly. The problem is when the user is off the grid, in which case c2dm messages stack up and get delivered all at once when he is back online. A cacaphony of notification sounds is the result from adding all the notifications in a 1 second period. How to prevent this? Desired behaviour is a that the notification sound is played once, while the tickertext and notification content are up to date with the last received message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using an alarm wich was set 1 second into the future. I set multiple alarms with the same intent, the earlier ones are automatically deleted. So when a second one comes in in the 1 second interval it deletes the first.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the collapse_key to only process the last "notification" of the stack

For more info, see https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages

Comment: This is not an option for me because I use messages with payload (ie not only that a new chat message is available, but also the body text). So if one message is collapsed, it is missed by my client.  If GCM would add a flag indicating that a previously sent message was deleted, I could contact the server and do a sync. But AFAIK there is no way of telling wether a message was collapsed.